# What is the difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties of CultureInfo in .NET?

Tags: .net, globalization, cultureinfo

In .NET there is the `CultureInfo` class in the `System.Globalization` namespace. It has two similar properties both returning values of the `CultureInfo` type: `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`.

What is the difference between them?

Which one should I use when and why?

Comment: Bear-in-mind that Microsoft, in their wisdom, don't separate the UI cultures of US English and (British) English or other Englishes. There's no MUI for English, which means the `CurrentUICulture` will always be en-US on an English-language machine, regardless of the `CurrentCulture`, which can be set to localise the Regional Settings.

Comment: Yes. I'm in the UK and find `CurrentCulture` is 'en-GB', but `CurrentUICulture` is 'en-US'.

Comment: Just found this article explaining this in detail: https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/CurrentCulture-vs.-CurrentUICulture

Answer (score 382, accepted):

`CurrentCulture` is the .NET representation of the default user locale of the system. This controls default number and date formatting and the like.

`CurrentUICulture` refers to the default user interface language, a setting introduced in Windows 2000. This is primarily regarding the UI localization/translation part of your app.

Whatever regional options the system is configured to have will be the "Current" values in your .NET app.

Often times they are both the same. But on my system they would be different: I prefer my numbers and dates in the German format, so the `CurrentCulture` would be German, but I also prefer all my applications in English, so the `CurrentUICulture` would be English.

There is a nice article on the topic: [Sorting it all Out: Why we have both CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture](http://www.siao2.com/2007/01/11/1449754.aspx)

Comment: Actually this might be a good alternative for in-depth explanation: http://forums.asp.net/post/1080435.aspx

Comment: @Michael12345 Thanks for the hint. I've updated the link. The post you link to is decent as well, maybe even better.

Comment: Those are terrible names, then, since CurrentUICulture really means CurrentLanguageCulture and CurrentCulture really means CurrentDataCulture.

Comment: @Pxtl: I'd opt for *CurrentFormattingCulture* rather than *CurrentDataCulture*. Still, note that these may not be as obviously disjoint as even your names suggest. For instance, I'd argue the long date format (`D`) can contain quite some "language": `en-US` returns "Friday, April 6, 2018", whereas `ru-RU` returns "6 апреля 2018 г.".

Answer (score 116):

This is a simple trick I use to remember which one to use:

```
(date, currency, double).tostring = CurrentCulture

resource.fr-CA.resx file = currentUICulture
```

Comment: If the comments by [nicodemus13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033#comment11872860_329033) and [Colonel Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033#comment18121804_329033) are to be trusted, it would seem the second part of your trick shouldn't work.

Answer (score 21):

A good way to make a difference in addition to the nice explanations done by fellow users, and  an important aspect in web application development is the following:

- `CurrentCulture` represents the setup of the web server. For example, if your ASP.NET web application is hosted in Germany, the value of `CutlureInfo.CurrentCulture` would most probably be `de-DE`. Thus, the default `.ToString()` formatting for `IFormattable` types would use the default German formattings, or the ones which have been set up on the server OS as defaults.
- `CurrentUICulture` can be captured from the user agent, and may represent the user interface culture of the client connecting to the website. For example, if you load that website from Russia, your local settings are set to use Russian language, and your user agent sends your locale settings to the server (Opera and IE do this automatically, not sure for Chrome and FireFox), the `CurrenUICulture` would represent `ru-RU`. This will cause any resources like localized strings retrieved via ResourceManager or localization expressions in ASP.NET aspx/ascx files to be in Russian (if translations are available).

Answer (score 19):

**Differences:**

1. [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) is for formatting of dates and currency while  [`CurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture) goes with language/translations. It will be used by [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) to look up resources by culture.
2. Namespace of  [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) class is in `System.Globalization` while  [`CurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture) comes from `System.Threading`.
3. [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) is persisted across different requests in the session while [`CurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture) needs to be set with every request.

**Likeness:**

They both are [`System.Globalization.CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo) instances.

Answer (score 14):

It is worth noting that the `CurrentUICulture` supports non-country specific locales such as 'en' (Neutral cultures) whereas `CurrentCulture` ONLY supports country specific locales such as 'en-GB'. Setting `CurrentCulture` to a neutral culture will throw an `ArgumentException`.

I assume that this is because formats such as dates and currency are more strongly linked to the country itself, but the language displayed is often interchangeable between countries.

Comment: A very good point indeed. Nevertheless, I would argue if `CurrentUICulture` is designed to be used for Neutral cultures only. You could successfully assign a specific culture with the `CurrentUICulture` and it would make sense if you have differences in the localization for certain countries operating with the same language.