# Localizing C# ASP.NET and Windows Forms Apps

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, localization

I need to localize existing ASP.NET and Windows Forms applications (C#, .NET 3.5).  I am looking for the best resources (books, articles, etc.) to learn how to do this and if there are any tools to help with making this easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000088/187650

Answer (score 0):

Are you localizing to a right-to-left language like Persian, Arabic or Hebrew?

Comment: No, I don't need to support that.

Answer (score 0):

for WPF localization see 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788718.aspx

sample project for localization in .net (project available for download)
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx

a very usefull site for standards - internationalization and etc
 http://www.i18nguy.com/

if you are interested in localization conferances you can see
 http://www.unicodeconference.com/
and
 http://www.localizationworld.com/

is it enough for you?

Comment: let me know if this answer help you or not