# C# Program Settings and Localizing

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, resources

So I'm starting my first actual Program in C# now, and just before I dig into the actual functions, I'm asking myself about localization of a Program.

I thought, a .resx is nice for the language-variables to store. But how can I get that into the settings? I see there is a .settings file, where I can assign Settings for the program, but how can I add my language.resx to these settings, so if there are several installed the user can select which language to use?

Furthermore, I'm designin the program using the winform designer - how can I tell a control to use a string of the resourcce as a text rather than type it in by hand?

I'm sure there are a bunch of tutorials out there concerning my issues, but 2 hours of searching haven't got me anywhere, so if anyone has some suggestions for me, I'd be very thankful =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be similar to question 1142802, so maybe [that is a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/c-localization-really-confusing-me/1142840#1142840).

ed:
It depends on the control a bit I guess, but for a menu you could create a method that [defines it's contents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menu.aspx).
You'd then be able to do something like `menuItem1.Text = string.Item1Text`.

Comment: That's okay, but just one part - the really interesting question is how to get the localized string into the WinForms, so that e.g. the menu is localizable