# Using resources for localization in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, asp.net-mvc-4, globalization

I'm following [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2010/05/06/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-3-days-investigation-1-day.aspx) tutorial that was given as answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776868/localization-using-resources-file-not-working) question, however I'm stuck at displaying the resource.

Just like in tutorial I've created two files

```
App_GlobalResources
   /Global.en.resx
   /Global.ru.resx
```

I've made data annotation class that works and adds a cookie with no errors, it means it injects the local data into current thread properly. When I try to output resource it cannot find it.

I've tried to output it like this and none of these works:

```
@Global.HomeHello
@Global.en.HomeHello
@Resources.Global.Homhello
// The name 'Resources/Global/etc...' does not exist in the current context
```

Also, in this tutorial site I see no logic that will inject the proper resource file, how it can do something like (in tutorial) `@Global.HomeHello` and it will know that if url is `/en/` he needs to use `Global.en.resx`

Please help, first time using resources and implementing multiple languages, feels 100 times more harder and confusing than using `*.yml` files in other frameworks/languages...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You took a bad example to follow I guess. Please look into the following article:

[Resource Files and ASP.NET MVC Projects](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx)

Don't forget to change `Custom Tool` to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and `Custom Tool Namespace` to `Resources`.

Hope this helps & good luck.

Comment: Okey, now I have two `*.resx` files in my `Languages` directory, both have class `Languages` and I can call `@Languages.English.HomeHello`. But now the big problem is, how can I do something like `@Languages.HomeHello` and it will pick correct `*.resx` file depending on my locale?