# Comma and (decimal) point: Do they need different handling?

Tags: c#, localization, internationalization, number-formatting, decimal-point

Just something that i was wondering about.
In Europe the comma us mostly used for decimals (like 20,001) but outside Europe the point is mostly used (like 20.001)
How does c# handle this ?
In case of a application that will be used by Europe and non-Europe people, do you need to worry about the above when programming ?

Just curious about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use localization in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Not a dupe, IMHO- the other question assumes that someone knows about localization, this one does not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as the *programming language* is concerned, the decimal point separator is always `.`, and the punctuation used to separate function arguments is always `,`. Changing that based on the spoken language of the programmer would be too confusing.

For the *user interface*, there are formatting functions in the [`CultureInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) that can produce a floating point number representation that uses the decimal point separator and thousands separator of your choice. (Or, for cultures that group digits of a number differently than in triplets, the formatting functions can handle that too.)

Comment: Ahaa yes that was exactly what i meant, what happens when the user uses point or comma in (for example) the textbox that in the code is used for inputvalue. But now is see, the programmer can set some separator so the code can understand, (and thus get the same input regardless of the . or ,) thanx for explenation

Comment: It's interesting that the entire programming language industry is US-centric -- there isn't a single language (that I know of) where a native European programmer could write three-and-a-half as 3,5 in his code.

Answer (score 7):

CultureInfo handles that situation.

Take a look at [this](http://www.csharp-examples.net/iformatprovider-numbers/)

```
// format float to string
float num = 1.5f;
string str = num.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);        // "1.5"
string str = num.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat); // "1,5"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, c# (and really, the whole .NET framework) have the concept of Cultures for this purpose:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CultureInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) to handle it. Just read and write with correct formatter.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what exactly you do... .NET is usually aware of the current settings of the machine/OS and uses those...

You should look into [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096) and see whether any of it is relevant in your case...