# how determine the writing language in c# win application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

**I** am developing a window application and I need to know what language is the current language
any help please ...
i really need to now that
how to determine current writing language ?

Comment: What exactly do you need to know? are you referring to [localization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: I dont know why your question got closed? I think you are looking for CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture (which refers to the current UI rather than the version installed) rather than CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly you can use:

```
CultureInfo currCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

To determine the language the machine is using.

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood correctly, but if you're speaking about the Regional Settings / Culture, you can use this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: I need to know the current writing language but this is showing the culture that windows was installed

Comment: mahdi, I don't understand what "writing language" means...