# Always returns the string with the default language from a resource file

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I have two resources files, `Emails.es.resx` (es-ES) and `Emails.eu.resx` (eu-ES), and I have a problem to retrieve a string from eu-ES file with `myLib.Emails.ResourceManager.GetString("textKey", "eu-ES");`

At local this works properly but at server, is a web app + IIS, not works, always return a correct value of "textKey" but with default language es-ES.

I cleaned the solution and rebuilded all, but without results.

Does anyone knows what could happen?

Comment: Did you try [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1142840/825024)?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but not working. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the correct culture. Suppose you have given option somewhere at website default page where user can choose language. On language change save the selected language in application state somewhere.. session or catch or whatever suite you. Set culture as following
[explained at following link:](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2005/08/08/localizingaspnet20.html?page=3)

```
  protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo lang = null;
    lang = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("zh-CN");

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = lang;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = lang;

}
```

Now retrieve your resources.. it should return correct one.

Comment: Retrieve your selected language/culture and use  instead of "zh-CN" in following line. System.Globalization.CultureInfo("zh-CN");

Comment: You should just pop this into the web.config file, a lot easier to change. There's a globalization tag in system.web where you can set these languages!

Comment: Yes, I tried change those properties but not working. Is it may have to change some options in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your files to `Emails.es-ES.resx` and `Emails.eu-ES.resx`