# What is the easiest way to change language in fixed code app?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can Visual studio list all fixed message in app(win app) and show me for editing to another language?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, No.

You can put all messages in a single file and edit at one place whenever needed.

But, I think you are talking about localization and this link can help: [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)