# Translation implementation

Tags: c#, user-interface, translate

I have created to `.resx` files: `Translate.English.resx` and `Translate.Romanian.resx` that contain strings like this:

```
MainWindowTitle : English Value
```

and in the Romanian file:

```
MainWindowTitle : Valoarea in Romana.
```

Now my question is: how tcan I force the program to interpret the the code like here:

- I have a `string` called `lang`, firstly equal with `en`.
- I have `MainWindow.Text = Translate.English.MainWindowTitle`
- Now I want it to be simpler to implement, so beside:

  ```
  switch(lang){
      case "ro":
          MainWindow.Text = Translate.English.MainWindowTitle;
      break;

      case "en":
          MainWindow.Text = Translate.Romanian.MainWindowTitle;
      break;
  }
  ```

So, beside that, I want it to be something like:

```
   lang = "ro";
   MainWindow.Text = Translate.(lang value).MainWindowText
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)  You'll have to rename your resx files to something like "translate.en.resx" and "translate.ro.resx".  Then you can do something like this:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en");
or
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ro");
MainWindow.Text = translate.MainWindowText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose Add New Item and Selected Resource Files in your project.

Give a name like String.resx,  String.ro.resx,  String.tr.resx,  String.fr.resx.

**Sample usage for 4 different language:**

```
  Console.WriteLine(Localize("name", "ro"));
  Console.WriteLine(Localize("name", "en"));
  Console.WriteLine(Localize("name", "fr"));
  Console.WriteLine(Localize("name", "tr"));


public static string Localize(string name, string languageCode)
{
  return Strings.ResourceManager.GetString(name, new CultureInfo(languageCode));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the guys above are right. Beside that you can also change the language in real time with something like that.

```
private void RefreshResources(Control ctrl, ComponentResourceManager res)
{
   ctrl.SuspendLayout();
   res.ApplyResources(ctrl, ctrl.Name, CurrentLocale);
   foreach (Control control in ctrl.Controls)
      RefreshResources(control, res); // recursion
   ctrl.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

If you want a complete example check my blog [here](http://codeuntil.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/localizable-forms-in-c-or-how-to.html)