# Where can I put static strings?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Im creating an *Windows Phone* app and I find myself writing the same `MessageBox.Show("Same error message")` multiple times. For instance

> "Could not connect to server"

This happens when the user do not have internet access.

Is there somewhere I can put it so that I write the text once and fetch the same text all over the place?

I could write a static class, but maybe there is a file for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be multi-lingual in the end I'd go for the Resource.resx file.

If not, you can go for all kinds of solutions:

- keep the string there where they make most sense, in the class where you use them
- store them all together in a dedicated class

Like:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private static string MyString = "blah";
    // other meaningful stuff
}
```

Or:

```
public class MyStaticStrings
{
    public static string MyString = "blah1";
    public static string AnotherString = "blah2";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there somewhere I can put it so that I write the text once and fetch the same text all over the place?

Yes, there is a special kind of file specifically for this, called `strings.resx`. It lets you write

```
MessageBox.Show(strings.ServerNotFound);
```

instead of

```
MessageBox.Show("Server not found");
```

The added benefit (in fact, the intended purpose) of using `strings.resx` is that your application becomes easily localizable ([see answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1142802/335858)): adding proper translations and setting the current locale is all it would take to change all strings that your application displays to users with their proper local translations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static variable in the App.xaml.cs page in the App class, so that you can access it all over the application.