# string to constant type in c#

Tags: c#, constants

We have constants defined in a static class along with functions like

```
public const string MSG_1 = "New error {0}" 
public const string MSG_2 = "Random error occurred {1}"

public static string Message_ToForm(string MType, string[] vals)

public static GetNewType(string MType)
{
  switch (MType)
    {
      case "MSG_1" :  ...........
    }
}
```

I require to call it from a program like 
Message_ToForm("MSG_1", string[]);

How can I convert it to get the value of the constant from string type?
Basically, it should return me as "New error {0} when "MSG_1" is passed?

Comment: If these are (as you've shown) being used to form error messages, you might want to look into storing them as resources. There's quite a bit of support in the framework for storing and retrieving resources (and then you don't really need this class or `Message_ToForm()` since you would just write `string.Format(MyResources.MSG_1,value1,value2)`)

Comment: @Rohan: Does the suggestions below, solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need a return type as String for your GetNewType

***Suggestion:***

If the constants are NOT reused and it if its ONLY for your lookup.

You could use a `Dictionary` to do the lookup

```
     Dictionary<string, string> constValues = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                                         {
                                                             {"MSG_1", "New error {0}"},
                                                             {"MSG_2", "Random error occurred {1}"}
                                                         };


    public string GetNewType(string MType)
    {
        if (constValues.ContainsKey(MType))
            return constValues[MType];

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: This solution achieved the results. I was looking for a solution where my message is getting constructed dynamically as well as for logging information, I required the constant name and not the actual value associated with the constant. All this was encapsulated within a class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really confused with your question, but think that's what you're looking for:

```
public static string GetNewType(string MType)
{
  switch (MType)
    {
      case "MSG_1": return MSG_1;
      case "MSG_2": return MSG_2;
      default: throw new ArgumentException("MType");
    }
}
```

But I must say - that's really bad approach! **You should rethink your design**.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a MessageType enumeration and switch based on that.

```
enum MessageType
{ 
   None = 0,
   Msg1,
   Msg2
}

public static string GetNewType(MessageType MType)
{
    string msg = string.Empty;
    switch (MType)
    {
      case MessageType.Msg1:
         msg = MSG_1;
         break;
      case MessageType.Msg2:
         msg = MSG_2;
         break;
    }
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a return type on your method. I believe this is what you want.

```
static string GetNewType(string MType)
{
   switch (MType)
      {
         case "MSG_1" :
            return MSG_1;
         case "MSG_2":
            return MSG_2;
      }
   return "";
}
```

But is there are reason your strings are saved as constants in variables? Couldn't you just return the strings in the switch? Like this:

```
switch (MType)
{
   case "MSG_1" :
      return "New error {0}";
   case "MSG_2":
      return "Random error occurred {1}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static readonly ReadOnlyDictionary property populated with your 'constants':

```
private static readonly System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> _msgDictionary =
    new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "MSG_1", "New error {0}" },
            { "MSG_2", "Random error occurred {1}" }
        });

public static System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> Messages
{
    get { return _msgDictionary; }
}
```

Then usage:

```
var msg = Messages["MSG_1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static GetNewType(string MType)
{
string MType = yourClass.MSG_1
  switch (MType)
    {
      case yourClass.MSG_1
        break;
          ....
        default:
       // Code you might want to run in case you are
       // given a value that doesn't match.
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using the out of the box .NET localization feature. You simply add a resource file to your project and put all your string messages into it, the resource file is like a key value pair of string resources, the IDE automatically creates a property for each string message which you can use in your code.

Check this [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) for more details.