# Localization with parameters of output message C#

Tags: c#, .net, localization

In my application I print messages, some are Debug and some need to fire up as popup window.
I must use Localization as described in: [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)
My question is, if my output is based on data member, how can i send it to the Value and use it in the resx file ?
My output log is:

```
string.Format("Operation Id = {0} has failed", opId);
```

But when i wish to add it as localized, I cant put in Value (in my output_messages.resx) the data member opId.

Comment: _But when i wish to add it as localized, I cant put in Value (in my output_messages.resx) the data member opId._

How come? Can you tell the error why you can't put it in the variable?

Comment: when using visual studio .resx editor for strings, It is not clear, that i can use {0} in it. I didnt know its possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You store the *format string*, i.e. the resx might contain:

```
Operation Id = {0} has failed
```

(against some key)

Then you can use:

```
string.Format(yourResources.WhateverNameYouUsed, opId);
```