# Can't find the method to show a message if a file is missing at startup

Tags: c#, file, message, startup, messagebox

Check all these images: [Screenshots of message](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=the%20program%20can%27t%20start%20because&biw=1920&bih=979&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidtYWV5rLNAhUlJMAKHXM7A-oQ_AUIBygC)

Most programs show the same message if a required file is missing. The title of the message is also translated if Windows language isn't English.

I can't find this method that is used by most Windows programs.

I know how to check if file exist and show a MessageBox (C#), but I want to use this Windows built-in method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) page.
There even is an example written in C#.

Comment: Can you send a link to the exmaple?

Comment: Scroll down a bit. But I would recommend you to use a 'normal' MessageBox. As far as I think there is a function in VS to translate your texts [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170102/translating-a-visual-studio-project).

Comment: It's not about the translation. I just want to use the same method of file checking like all other programs in Windows.

Comment: You asked about a Windows-built-in-MessageBox.
Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) and maybe you will find what you are searching for.

Comment: It is only an explanation about the Windows API. I read it and didn't find what I am searching for.