# How to localize inline strings in a windows forms strings?

Tags: c#, localization, windows-forms-designer

I want to localize my C# windows forms application. I handled to localize the strings on controls by setting their language and values one by one, and I have form1.en.resx and form1.fr.resx and when I run it works as I expected (french in french pc's english in english pc's). But I couldn't find out how will I do that for other strings in the code. Let's say I have:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
```

I believe I need something like

```
MessageBox.Show(Resources.Helloworld);
```

And according to the language of the pc it should select the rigth resource value as other control texts do. What is the rigth way to do such a thing?

I tried resharpers `Move to resource` option. But it only moves to resource of the project hence I cannot specify any language option on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This link][1] is really what I've been looking for. Thanks.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
  public enum myResource
    {
        HelloWorld,
        ByeWorld
    }



public string GetText(myResource someRes)
        {
            string sText = "";
            switch (someRes)
            {
                case someRes.HelloWorld:
                    sText = "Hello World";
                    break;
                case someRes.ByeWorld:
                    sText = "ByeWorld";
                    break;
                default:
                    sText = "Empty...";
                    break;
            }

            return sText ;

        }
```