# ReportViewer: Two rldc files with same DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource, reportviewer

I have a report working fine, but now I need develop the same report in other language (english btw).Same layout, same fields.

So I created another .rdlc file and other winform (Maybe it's possible use the same winform, I saw something like that on my research)

My problem is: 
After I set all fields and layout, when I select .rdlc file on "choose report" in ReportViewer and do the same way I was doing. Something  isn't  right  because I not getting all BindingSource and all TableAdapter automatically.

On .rdlc file I add all DataSet from DataSource that I was needing.

I Try add manually the TableAdapter from Toolbox because it's showing all components from the other report, but doesn't work.

What is the best way to do something like that? two rdlc file with same data, same DataSource.

I'm thinking create another DataSource file (.xsd).

(sorry my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same data but different languages? Try this:

1. use a single RDLC file with a boolean parameter like `blnEnglishLanguage`
2. for every TextBox used as label set an expression like this: `=IIf(Parameters!blnEnghlishLanguage.Value, "Item", "Articolo")`

BONUS: give a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) to localize your form: 
see accepted answer and the answer provided by noelicus.

Comment: Thank you, very useful your answer!

Answer (score 0):

what i have don is.
you need to set a parent window to IsMdiContainer = true.
and then you can open the windows forms with the report in the same parent.
Remove the form border of the windows form report windows

with the code for the buttons to open it in the mdi Container

```
    awDushiHomesClients OpenawViewClients;
    private void ViewClientsMenuB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (OpenawViewClients == null)
        {
            OpenawViewClients = new awDushiHomesClients();
            OpenawViewClients.MdiParent = this;
            OpenawViewClients.FormClosed += OpenawViewClients_FormClosed;
            OpenawViewClients.Show();
        }
        else
            OpenawViewClients.Activate();
    }

    void OpenawViewClients_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenawViewClients = null;
        ///throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

for the second button use the same code but rename all awDushiHomesClients to lets say awDushiHomesClientsEng."But then your file name"

don't know what kind of information you are showing but if you just need to rename the column text copy and past the first report and rename it.