# WPF Localization not working from code behind

Tags: c#, localization

I have two resource files: `StaticData.resx` and `StaticData.de-ch.resx`

After I change my CultureInfo, the UI reflects the change perfectly.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(Settings.Default.Localization);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

XAML

```
Title="{x:Static language:StaticData.Title}"
```

When I try to access this from my code behind, I only get the data from StaticData.resx

```
var title = StaticData.Title;
```

What am I doing wrong? According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)
it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the  `var title = StaticData.Title;` was called from a different Thread the CultureInfo Need to we set to the correct format again