# How to get same variable from multiple resource files

Tags: c#, .net, resx, multiple-languages

I am developing a small project about using multiple language.

I have three resource files

1. MainForm.resx // Default version => English
2. MainForm.US.resx // English version

I define
[image]

3. MainForm.JP.resx // Japanese version

I define
[image]

I want to get value of each variable (btnCancel, btnLogin, lbPassword, lbUsername, ...)

Now, I do

- From MainForm.US.resx, I build to MainForm.US.designer.cs (MainForm_US class)
- From MainForm.JP.resx, I build to MainForm.JP.designer.cs (MainForm_JP class)
- I make another class MainFormResource.cs. Here, I will check Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name value
- If is equal "ja-JP", I get value from MainForm.JS.designer.cs (MainForm_JP class)
- If is equal "en-US", I get value from MainForm.US.designer.cs (MainForm_US class)

But if my project is large, it will take me more time to do that.

How should I do to get the value of lbUsername, lbPassword, ...?

p/s: I use **Windows Form Application** in **Visual Studio Ultimate 2012**

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks @NightOwl888, but I use winform for my app.

Answer (score 0):

When creating RESX files you only need to activate the automatic code generation on the root file (MainForm.resx in your case).

Visual Studio will generate the code which includes the usage of `RescourceManager`.

The satellite assemblies will also be generated automatically.

So as NightOwl888 already mentioned, you should read the documentation about using Resx files and [globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c08a467e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) / localization features of .NET

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. But document's NightOwl888 use with ASP.NET

Comment: Look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp), it should solve your general problem.

Comment: Re: _"The satellite assemblies will also be generated automatically."_ In my (limited) experience with satellite assemblies, that is not the case. You have to have one project per satellite assembly in your solution.

Comment: No, the satellite assemblies containing the resources for each culture (de, en, en-US, etc.) will be generated automatically.

Comment: Thansk @RobinGüldenpfennig again. It works for me (above comment +1)