# Translate "True" to "Verdadero" in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization

As documented in the [Boolean.ToString(IFormatProvider) method doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/s802ct92(v=vs.110).aspx), the `IFormatProvider provider` does not impact the constant "True/False" output.

Now, is there a way to however translate the  "True" to "Verdadero"?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Your code goes here
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
    Console.WriteLine(true.ToString(ci));
}
// Hello, world!
// True
```

Comment: As the first two answers below suggest - you can either use a conditional statement or an extension method - but rather than use strings as in the answers use localizable string resources. See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Ðаn: without further input from OP, then it is difficult to say - but what would you suggest as an improvement over the answers so far.

Comment: I see you have posted my comment as an answer including the same link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a library-based solution to your question, *nor should there be*.  The reason is that a string representation of `System.Boolean` is unlikely to be useful for anything but the most trivial of localization.  Note that is not the case for floating-point numbers where a culture-specific `.` or `,` can be applied when formatting.  Dates (`System.DateTime`) have some localization support from the operating system itself, so .NET is able to build on that; this is not the case for `System.Boolean`.

Usually, there will be other words in addition to just "True" (or "False"); those words will have to be translated too.  And, depending on the language and those other words, you might not be able to do simple string concatenation: `string message = baseMessage + b.ToString();`

Instead, you should store your strings in resource files and retrieve the right one.

```
bool b = ...;
string message = b ? Properties.Resources.TrueMessage : Properties.Resources.FalseMessage;
```

See [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) for more details.

Comment: I am not the only one asking about that, so I don't know about "unlikely". If is not useful, why does Microsoft returned "True" as bool.ToString() instead of "1"/"0"? Why "True" and not "Vrai", "Varadero" or "OK"... More frustrating it has a IFormatProvider as parameter... so Anglophone users are favored over others: `"C'est vrai ?:" + true.ToString(new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))`

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, `Boolean.ToString(IFormatProvider)` will not reflect culture specific strings.

However, one workaround could be to create an extension method on the `Boolean` object:

```
public static class BoolExtensions
{
    public static string ToSpanishString(this bool val)
    {
        return val ? "Verdadero" : "Falso";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if a global library based solution exists or not. However you can pass an optional CultureInfo and start an if ... else if .... else block to handle the culture you are interested to where in case of missing CultureInfo you return the default TrueString or FalseString from the Boolean class..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in the following way:

```
bool test = true;
Console.WriteLine(test ? "Verdadero" : "Equivocado");
```

The first value is always the truthy one, the second is the falsy.

Comment: @Ðаn Well, I did not use `ToString()`, but I answered the question `Now, is there a way to however translate the "True" to "Verdadero"?`

Comment: @Ðаn That's one possibility to solve the problem. I presented another

Comment: @Ðаn I understand, what you mean. But I am honestly conviced I answered the question, which is asked.