# C# How to read language from file

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am working to create a multilang Application, and i want to read the "array" from file, i don t know from where to start.

My english.lang looks like:

```
LOGIN_TITLE = Test login
LOGIN_CREATE_ACC_LABEL = Create an account
LOGIN_REMEMBER_ME_CHECKBOX = Remember Me
LOGIN_AUTO_LOGIN = Auto Login
LOGIN_STATUS_WELCOME = Welcome to Client
LOGIN_STATUS_WRONG = Invalid username or password
LOGIN_SING_IN_BUTTON = Sing In
```

And i am looking for smth like:

```
string = getLang("LOGIN_TITLE");
```

I have an ideea about how to do, but is not optimal, i am thinking to do smth like: read from file line by line up to line who contains "LOGIN_TITLE" and then replace "LOGIN_TITLE = " with blank, and the remains should be "Test login", the string i needed

I think it will have low performance if my lang file is too big.

Do you have any ideea about how to do that?

Comment: It's not duplicate, i needed smth like that, but for file, like english.lang, in this link it s for resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Header header = new Header(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Header
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public Header(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            string inputLine = "";

            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();

                string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { '=' }).ToArray();
                dict.Add(inputArray[0].Trim(), inputArray[1].Trim());

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way is using resource file in multi languages application;

look this [site](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/580043/How-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-Csharp)

and chage the away. working with text file will be get your time what is important

Comment: It's more easy to work with res files, and i will move to work with. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you better **NOT** do it yourslef.

Localization is most common problem in end-user application development and were solved long ago your question came up. Please, see another answer on stackoverflow: [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

*Fredrik Mörk* briefly explains how to create/use resource localization files in your code and gives simple example.

Comment: This is smth i am looking for, i think i will move to resources files :-? it's more easy to work with