# Visual Studio 2015: Solutionexplorer -> Any Project ->Properties --> Rightclick missing the "add item" option || Diffrent context menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I rightlick on `Properties` in the `Solutionexplorer` there are 2 Items missing in that List.
One of them is the "add item" option
**EDIT: Actually the conext menus are totally diffrent - WAT**

[image: AS seen here]

A friend of mine has the missing options

[image]

I am currently using

- Visualstudio 2015 Enterprise
- Version 14.0.25431.01
- Update3

Anyone know the option where I activate them?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142840/5757162) is why I am trying to do it this way.

Comment: As a Bonus, why does he have a totally diffrent context menu?

Comment: Did you try with the same projects? Same extensions installed?

Comment: yes yes we did.

I even checked a clean isntallation on the server didn't have it there either Oo

Comment: Thing is, I think not having the Add menu is actually standard (which explains why you don't have it nor a clean installation has it, and I also don't have it) and your friend has some extension or setting or so which enables it.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1142840/5757162) guy has it also. Its accepted as standard reply from 2009 if i am not mistkaen. So I am wondering why they have it and me not.

Comment: There is always an add menu item, unless you have started a debug session or something similar that disallows adding of items at the moment...

Comment: Also possibility:  Does the Properties folder physically exist or is it a virtual folder. ( if it was made in older Visual Studio's--> physical location)

Comment: the folder exists