# .NET MVC localized resource file is not read

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

I was trying to add some satellite resource files to display different language
I followed these two posts in general

[stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

[Localization of a Site in MVC5 Using Resource File](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/localization-of-a-site-in-mvc5-using-resource-file/)

here's what I have done in nutshell (using visual studio 2017, .net framework 4.5)

I created a folder named it "Resources"

I right clicked this folder and created a file named it "Lang.resx", added a string pair (name: Welcome, value: Hello), then switch it to public and save

I right clicked this folder and created another file named it "Lang.es.resx", added a string pair (name: Welcome, value: Hola), then switch it to public and save

I opened up web.config and added following line to System.Web

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
```

I opened up a blank view, write the following to that view

```
@{ 
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");
}

<div>@MyProject.Resources.Lang.Welcome</div>
<div>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName</div>
<div>@Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName</div>
```

The output is as following:

Hello
Spanish
Spanish

As you can see, the culture is changed but somehow the Lang.es.resx is not read, I have created multiple new project in different hosting VPS, the result is always the same. 
So there must be something I've done incorrectly, or some steps missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after a whole day debugging, I've found out the cause

1. When using resource file, it creates additional folder to the current bin folder, say Language.es.resx, then it creates a folder called es
2. When I upload the project to the ftp server, this language folder didn't get created and the es recource.dll file was not uploaded

I think this is it, hopefully this can help anyone facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In the file properties in Visual Studio, set:

Copy to output directory: Copy always

If you want for multiple files within a folder, you can always edit your .csproj file

```
<Content Include="parent directory\*.*">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```