# How can I localize XtraMessageBox Strings

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

i am using DevExpress XtraForm and I set a localizable property to true now i have three language English Arabic Franch each one with their resource file[image]

and i add this code to the Program

```
            if(Properties.Settings.Default.Language== "Français")
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-fr");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-fr");
        }
        else if (Properties.Settings.Default.Language == "العربية")
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-ar");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ar-ar");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        }
```

all work fine .
But I couldn't find a way to localize XtraMessageBox Strings
for example

```
 XtraMessageBox.Show("Remplissez tous les champs, s'il vous plaît ", "Manque de données", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually edit resource files to add required strings and manually obtain them in your code. I suggest you review the [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) thread where this is described in detail.