# Overriding localization strings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resx

I have a C# WPF project in which I have implemented localized language strings as answered in this question: [How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

The problem is that we need to be able to override certain strings to say something else for certain users, either regardless of language or by changing the string a single language. These changes should not be overwritten when the program updates.

In other words I want what you can do with settings with a user settings file, with localization resources too.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think, that you can just store your localized values into different .resx files and use using WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine to get them.

So you can get the localized value using WPFLocalizeExtension.Engine.LocalizeDictionary.Instance.GetLocalizedObject(), where you can pass the dictionary name as a parameter.

Comment: @RubenMartirosyan Is there no way to do it while using the existing designer and simple lookup via the auto generated properties?