# WPF Localization of dynamic string in TextBlock

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.1 WPF application. I need to localize a string in a **TextBlock** element, using standard **.resx** files.

The problem is, in my TextBlock, I use a dynamic resource, consisting out of a text and an increasing number (counter).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding LoadingPercent, StringFormat=Loading the app...{0:N0}%}" />
```

Do you know how to localize this text "Loading the app..." in XAML?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe you could bind the StringFormat as well, so you could bind the StringFormat to a property and fill it with the correct string

Answer (score 3):

Localize only "Loading the app..." and split the `TextBlock` into two `Run` elements:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{x:Static local:Resources.LoadingLabel}" />
    <Run Text="{Binding LoadingPercent, StringFormat=P0}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to move the format string part to a resource, and use this with MultiBinding like the following:

```
 <TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Text>
         <MultiBinding StringFormat="{x:Static local:Resource1.LoadTheAppFormated}">
             <Binding Path="LoadingPercent"/>
         </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

EDIT:
Your resource entry Resource1.LoadTheAppFormated should of course contain the whole formatted string "Loading the app...{0:N0}%".
For Localizing you will then need the extra *.en.resx ([How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp))