# Im trying to internationalize my site, by translating just the labels into the local language based on the browser language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, translate

My approach is to save all the label names, content, language and the page name on the database and retrieve it before every page load. Is this the right approach or can I do something more efficient. Assume I already have all the translated label names.

-- There would be frequent changes on the translations, so I prefer not to deploy the code all the time. So, resource file would be my last choice. (My understanding is that we would have to recompile the code everytime we change the .resx file, please correct me if im wrong)

Comment: If you do a search on `asp.net mvc i18n` you should find *plenty* of resources with various approaches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

you should look at globalization & localization in ASP.NET; see below links :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://afana.me/archive/2011/01/14/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx/
- http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application

Answer (score 0):

you can use Resource Files concept For Changing Label text

http://www.codedigest.com/posts/53/create-multi-language-website-in-aspnet-mvc---localization

Comment: Thank you but there would be frequent changes on the translations, so I prefer not to deploy the code all the time. So, resource file would be my last choice. (My understanding is that we would have to recompile the code everytime we change the .resx file, please correct me if im wrong)