# How to create multi-language app using wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, resources

I'm new to WPF. I'm trying to create a multi-language application using resources file. I have combobox to choose language and textblocks to display the changes. I don't know where to start. So if you have any link to reference, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways in which you can translate your application.
You can use resx files to translate the program depending on the language settings.

The following guides could help you:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_localization.htm

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files

[How to use localization in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you handling `.resx` files, please have a look at the [ResxManager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager) addon for Visual Studio.

[image]

This addon shows all string translations in a grid with all implemented language as columns and it provides many facilities to help you manage translation, like showing red grid cell on missing translation, translation services, etc...