# asp.net multiligual website culture settings

Tags: asp.net, multilingual

In asp.net multilingual website in english Uk and swedish, i have three rsources file

```
1. en-GB.resx
2. sv-SE.resx
3. Culture neutral file.
```

I have create one base class and all pages is inherited from that class. There i write following lines to set UICULTURE and culture

```
1. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name;
2. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;
```

Question: Suppose my browser language is Swedish(sv-SE) then this code will run because it find `CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture values as sv-SE.`

Now if suppose browser language is Swedish(sv) only, in that case values will be set as

```
CurrentUICulture = sv; and CurrentCulture = sv-SE
```

Now the problem is that user can able to view all text in Culture neutral resource file that i kept as english while all decimal saperators, currency and other will be appear in swedish.
It looks confusing to usr.

What would be right approach. I am thinking following solution. Please correct me?

```
1. i can create extra resource file for sv also.
2. I check value of CurrentUICulture in base class and if it is sv then replace it with sv-SE
```

Please correct me which one is right approach or Is there any other good way of doing?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily replace the value in the base class like you mentioned. I would stay away from creating an additional resource file that duplicates data since it will be harder to maintain.

```
 if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() != "sv")
      ...replace with sv-SE
```

**EDIT** See this other question][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of) for additional info. There's a good article referenced in the answer of that question

Comment: I think no need to check also. because already we have sv-SE with CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name; and i can assign this value for both like this way
1. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name; 
2. Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name

What do you say?

Comment: You can definitely do this if you don't need to have numbers in one culture and text in another.