# CurrentUICulture and new created CultureInfo Instance

Tags: c#, globalization

I'm trying to find out program's language and change my string for this language

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en");
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
string msg="";
if (currentCulture == culture)
{
    msg = "Some words";
}
```

Even though values of culture and currentCulture are the same `if` statement is not working and my msg string is not changing.

Here is my debug results

Name--Value--Type

culture -- {en} -- System.Globalization.CultureInfo

currentCulture -- {en} -- System.Globalization.CultureInfo

Comment: Maybe your current culture is `en`. Try debugging

Comment: Maybe your current culture is `en-US`. Also have a look at the difference between `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of

Comment: "`if` statement is not working" - not working *how*? I *guess* it's not throwing an exception. It just evaluates `currentCulture == culture` to be `false` and does not enter the body (in other words: it works perfectly fine). Are you sure, your `CurrentUICulture` is "en" and not maybe "en-US" or something else?

Comment: I updated my question. My debug results are seems equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your culture could be represented as `en-Us`. Debug your code first. That might be the problem.

`CultureInfo` is a class, so it is a *reference type*. When you compare two different reference with `==`, it always return `false`. You can try to compare them based their [`CultureInfo.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.name.aspx) property for example. Like;

```
if(currentCulture.Name == culture.Name)
{
   msg = "Some words";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CultureInfo` is a reference-type without an override of `Equals()` so 2 separate instances will always be unequal.

This little piece of code will print **False**:

```
  var c1 = new CultureInfo("en");
  var c2 = new CultureInfo("en");
  Console.WriteLine(c1 == c2);
```

You can compare on a property, `Name` and `LCID` seem good candidates.