# Using the correct ".resx" file according to the culture info

Tags: c#, resx

I want to use localization in my project so I'm using ".resx" files.

I have two files "StringRes.resx" and "StringRes.fr.resx". As you can guess, I want that all the messages of my app change according to the CultureInfo of the user.

But when I do this :

```
public MainWindow()
{
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr");
     InitializeComponent();
}
```

It doesn't change anything when I do :

```
Console.WriteLine(StringRes.FirstName);
```

Indeed, it's always the string in StringRes which is displayed and not the string from StringRes.fr

The both are in the same namespace.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The resx files works off whatever window's culture is, I'm think there is an application culture somewhere [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/329041/1324033)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have created my own test projected an I used `"fr-FR"` as a culture tag. The test project can be found on [my skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=42FA0BD534D1D672!109) and [archived GitHub](https://github.com/synercoder/WpfCultureExample).

Works perfect.

[image: Culture test]

In short:

I set the culture in the Properties of the project to be en-US as that is what I would want my `Resource.resx` to be.

Then I created `Resource.resx`, `Resource.fr-FR.resx` and `Resource.nl-NL.resx`.

I filled them with the `TestData` string. And the created a window with 3 buttons with events hooked to them. Next to the buttons I created a textblock, the textblock is binded to a Text string field.

In the button events I change the culture and the `Text` field. And you can then see the change happen.

---

You first need to create your `Resource.resx` then in the same folder you need to create `Resource.fr-FR.resx`. The Resource.resx will get a codebehind file, all the cultured resource files should not. If your Resource.fr-FR.resx does have a culture file you did something wrong and it is best to delete that resources file and recreate it so it loses it's codebehind.

Comment: I've done as you've suggested and look at your sample and it works !
My Resource.fr-FR.resx has a codebehind file so I've recreated as you said and i don't have problems anymore.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well then, congratulations on your first answered question! Please accept the answer to let other people know this answer helped you. You also get +2 reputation for accepting an answer. For more information about reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Thank you for the details about the order of adding the resource files.  2 hours into figuring out why mine were not working I found this post and it solved my problem too.

Comment: Wish you hadn't put all the relevant info in an external download link which could fail later.

Comment: @IronSean what failed? I downloaded the ZIP again and it is working.  Also, the answer contained all the explaination of what is happening.

Comment: @IronSean Updated the project to .NET6 and uploaded it to github