# Strange behaviour using resources in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, resx

I have a strange behaviour in my WPF application using resources (`.resx`) for localization.

In `Properties` I created a new folder named Resources where I put my resx file. I created two files named `Resources.resx` and `Resources.it-IT.resx`.

In `App` class I did the overriede of method `OnStartup`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
}
```

What I expect is that the application starts in italian but starts in english (default in file `Resources.resx`).

I tried to change the name of resource for italian language from `Resources.it-IT.resx` to `Resources.it.resx`. Then I changed part where I set culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("it");
```

In this way application starts in italian.

I don't understand were's the problem. Why culture info not works with `it-IT`? I already tried with methods `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo` and `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture`.

Furthermore, `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` is already set as italian, but if I don't create new `CultureInfo` it doesn't work. Why?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351687/using-the-correct-resx-file-according-to-the-culture-info) question but the problem is different. I can change culture but I would like to know why it works only with `TwoLetterISOLanguageName`.

I tried with french (`fr-FR` with file `Resources.fr-FR.resx`) language and there's no problems.

Comment: What mjwills said.  I set up a tiny demo application and had no trouble.  Compare what you've got to the example on the link mjwills posted.  Above you said, "In Properties I created a new folder named Resources where I put my resx file."  I'm using VS 2017 and was not able to create a folder in Resources.  I just added my resource files directly to Resources.

Comment: @JordanWilcken I created folder outside of properties. Then I drag and drop the folder in properties. By the way, I tried with french (`fr-FR`) and there's no problem. The problem is with italian (`it-IT`).

Comment: Make sure the resource file for italian has the build action set as "Embedded Resource" (right-click on the file, then properties).

Comment: @IsmaC. Build action is ok