# What does UICulture in csproj file do?

Tags: .net, wpf, localization, csproj

To use the Multilingual App Toolkit I have to uncomment the NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs. This works but the comment above the attribute advises me to add a UICulture to my csproj file. I did so but this breaks my application. I couldn't find any documentation for UICulture.

What does UICulture do? Is it for applications that use LocBaml?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of) helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determines the culture used by the resource manager.
When UICulture is specified, the baml is embedded in a satellite assembly created under the folder with the same name as UICulture. At runtime depending on the default UI culture of windows, appropriate satellite assembly is used. I think the issue in your case is that the application is not able to find a satellite assembly matching your windows ui culture.

Im not a total expert on this but go look at

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bceb5cf9-761b-426f-9bf4-9c158e4b7de8

Comment: This solves the issue for `ResourceDictionary` references into libraries via pack URIs (e. g. `pack://application:,,,/LibraryName;component/resources.xaml`) failing as well when adding the `UICulture` element to the project file!