# Set culture language from code in Windows 10 UAP C#

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone-8.1, resources, windows-10

I create main folder "Strings" with folders en,eu etc.
Then i create resource file and fill it. All wark.
Can i change Application Language from code? For example add language to comboBox and then after click on combobox change my language?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CurrentUICulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. In your combobox you can have a list of cultures or strings like "en-US", "nl-BE", etc.

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // replace en-US with the selected culture or string from the combobox
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Also interesting to know: [What is the difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties of CultureInfo in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of)

Comment: thanls, but it's namespase doesn't present in windows 10 uap, but i found this
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-RU"); // replace en-US with the selected culture or string from the combobox
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
but it's don't work for me ;(