# WPF: Get default system language

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I am working on a small wpf application, and I a dropdown box to select the language.

Now I have an option in my dropdown box to select system default language.
(In this case the language from the windows system).

[image: Language dropdown]

I used the following code to actually **set the system default language**:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
```

But it actually **always give back English** even when I select **French as my main windows language**.

What is the correct way to actually change this.

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the final `else` and check what `language`'s value is?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL When I select system default it only comes in the first else, and there CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture will not give the correct value.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I removed the code to make the question clearer.

Comment: Not sure if its relevant, but [What is the difference between CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties of CultureInfo in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yea I know that part :) it is really about the installedUICulture not giving the correct windows language

Comment: Then it might actually be a bug. My last attempt at a suggestion: "So you must set the culture before the InitializeComponent method is called.", which I saw from [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for Windows Forms Globalization ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b28bx3bh%28VS.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)