# Not printing characters like 'Č' 'Ć' in my Culture

Tags: c#, itext, character, culture

I changed culture to my, Serbian Latin, culture, so i can have characters  'Č' 'Ć'

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sr-SP-Latn");
```

Anybody knows why?
Im using iTextSharp 5.1 for making pdf

Comment: "can have characters" where  ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to alter the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: Not sure it's the answer for you, but here's a link that explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/329041/6668786

Comment: *"so i can have characters 'Č' 'Ć'"* - which characters you can use,  does not depend on the culture. In itext you have to **a** use a font that includes the characters and **b** use a encoding for that font which supports them.