# C#: ShortDatePattern giving incorrect result

Tags: c#

I have `dd-MM-yyyy` date pattern for my windows machine. In below code I'm trying to get date format through C# code, but it's giving me `M/d/yyy` instead of `dd-MM-yyyy`. In code is correct ?

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

  Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

[image]

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;` (not `CurrentUICulture`)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm using. Question - why it's give incorrect result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of

Comment: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2007/01/11/1449754.html

Comment: Bingo, it's working, Thanks @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: `CurrentUICulture` refers to the first language that is displayed under "Region & Language" in windows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `CurrentCulture` instead of CurrentUICulture`.

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`

`CurrentCulture` is for formatting of numbers and dates.
`CurrentUICulture` for localisation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

You are using `CurrentUICulture` which is used for localisation instead use CurrentCulture which is used for  formatting of numbers and dates

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it through code as I can't hard-code

Comment: @Mr.Roshan - If you provided even a little explanation then your answer would be better.

Comment: @Mr.Roshan - That's worse.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use: `DateTime.Now.ToString("d");`
Documentation about DateTime formatting can be found here: [Standard DateTime Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.85).aspx)