# Force localization be in specific language in specific controller

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have a web-api project that has several controllers, I implemented localization (English and Korean) for it but want one or two controllers return messages in English even when the language is Korean (don't want use simple English message and want to read from English resource)

Is it possible?

I setup localization like below:

```
 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var cultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("kr")
                };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en");
                options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
            });

            services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>factory.Create(typeof(SharedTranslate));
            });
            services.AddLocalization(o =>
            {
                o.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
            });
```

and in constructor :

```
public AuthAdminController(IStringLocalizer<SharedTranslate> localizer,...
```

I use below code in constructor of controller but didn't work

```
//First
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            //Second
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
```

Comment: Yes. You can set: `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ...` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ...` by yourself. Something like that.

Comment: @Ergis I add it in constructor of controller but not work

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: Please share [mcve].

Comment: @SajjadZare it has to work. I've just recently done it. Put a debugger point and check what is the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` right before you return the View

Comment: How did you set up the localization? can you post that too? If you are injecting `IStringLocalizerFactory` or a wrapper over that then from your controller, you can 
 enforce to send English as language code.

Comment: @user1672994 I edited the question and add some code

Comment: @Ergis I edited the question and add some code

Comment: You have to set the `CurrentUICulture`. Fully read the word, it has a `UI` in it :D Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329033/what-is-the-difference-between-currentculture-and-currentuiculture-properties-of) important piece of information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following code while retrieving the localized string in `AuthAdminController`

```
 CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("<<Your language Code>>");
 var localizedString = localizer[resourceKey].Value;
 CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("<<Reset to default one>>");
 return localizedString;
```

The first line setting the `CurrentUICulture` and 3rd line resetting to default one.